# Dowload a file from the web through a Python call (javascript popup on the source site)

Tags: javascript, python, download, automation

i want to achieve 2 things:

1. automate the download of a csv file from this site https://www.investing.com/equities/assura-group-historical-data
2. automatically select the date range from a python call.

How can i make it happen? Thought of it as a kind of webscraping, but it is not really webscraping, it is more automated download of a file.

The problem is a javascript popup whenever i click on the download button.
So i am struggling in finding an automated solution.

Many thanks for your help.

UPDATES:
I followed the below suggestions but (as i am a very beginner), I stop here and i have no idea how to build the request with all the info. This is what i got from the browser:

*Method*
POST

*Url*
https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax

*Request Header*
Host: www.investing.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 171
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://www.investing.com/equities/assura-group-historical-data
Cookie:

*Request Body*
curr_id=7351&smlID=1160667&header=AGRP+Historical+Data&st_date=01%2F01%2F2001&end_date=09%2F26%2F2019&interval_sec=Daily&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data

Is this the right info needed to be able to create a python call and make the download automated?
How can i put it togehter?

Please bear in mind that after i select the date range there is still a popup window for download and nothing is shown in the debugger when this event is triggered.

[Please check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3kxA.png)
Thanks.

[b]UPPDATE 2[/b]
Trying this but it is not working:

```
import requests
headers = {'Host': 'www.investing.com','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0', 'Accept': 'text/plain, */*; q=0.01','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest','Content-Length': '171','Connection': 'keep-alive','Referer': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/assura-group-historical-data'}
payload = {'curr_id':'7351','smlID':'1160667','header':'AGRP+Historical+Data','st_date':'01%2F01%2F2001','end_date':'09%2F26%2F2019','interval_sec':'Daily','sort_col':'date','sort_ord':'DESC','action':'historical_data}
session = requests.Session()
session.post('https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax',headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Comment: A good start usually for this kind of things is to open your browser developer tools on the "Network" tab. Then, download the CSV you want. There is a good chance that there will be a request that asks the server to generate the file with the dates in the payload. You can then try to mimic that request in Python (URL, method, headers, payload, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You may find some info using browser's developer tools (usually found pressing `F12`), `Network` tab.

You can see then how is built the request, in which format dates are specified, and you can replicate it in Python.

I usually use [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org//en/master/) library for HTTP calls.

Comment: Thanks for this so far. I am a very beginner and tried to find out more by myself... but i am stopping here:

I gathered all the info that I believe are relevant, but don't know how to put them together to make the request from python code.
Below I will post the info.

Comment: Hmmm, now I see that there is also a login involved in. What if you download the file , get the file download address from the browser downloads page and copy it? If you paste that link in another browser window does it work? If so, and if the file link has the dates parameters you need, you can use just that.

Comment: actually it is not required to be logged in, anybody can download the file. The problem is that i cant see any link to download the file, i can only click on the download button and then it wil lopen up the download window (where i need to confirm manually where i want to download the file). So this is all the biggest troubles i am facing.. and still want to be able to set the date as well...through a python call. So 2 things i want to achieve: set the date range AND ALSO download the file through a python call.

Comment: yup, after you download the file you should be able to see it in your download history and copy the download url - that you can analyze.

Comment: yes but it is kind of encrypted and have no idea how this gets generated: blob:https://www.investing.com/df7da0d2-1ac4-2841-937d-2782b153f983